# Grep command linux regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

command: **grep kishan /etc/passwd**

output: **kishan:x:1000:1000:Kishan Kotadiya,,,:/home/kishan:/bin/bash**

I want just the user full name "**Kishan Kotadiya**" can you help me with that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is yet another fantastic example of a poorly asked question.  Could you please visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk one liner, **replaces your grep too**:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '/kishan/{print $5}' /etc/passwd 
Kishan Kotadiya
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut` on the output to get the 5th `:` separated substring, then reverse it, strip the 3 leading chars (which are `,` characters) and then reverse the string back to its original order.

```
grep kishan /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5 | rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```